# What does _ mean in this filter callback?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm struggling with the following piece of code that filters an array with repeated items but keeps the non-repeated items.

```
temp = temp.filter((a, _, aa) => aa.indexOf(a) === aa.lastIndexOf(a));
```

What I been seeing in the docs is that `Array.prototype.filter` takes a callback function with an element, an index and an array.

What I don't understand is the arguments that are being passed: `(a, _, aa)`. Is `_` used as a placeholder or does it represent something else?

Comment: `_` is commonly used as a "throwaway" argument. It's just a placeholder with no use here.

Comment: @AndrewLi Cool! Thanks man! That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The underscore in the argument list is just passed as a placeholder. It's commonly used to signal an argument that's thrown away and never used but needs to be there as a placeholder. Essentially a "dummy" variable.<sup>1</sup>

In this case, `Array.prototype.filter` takes in a callback with three arguments. Since the author of the code wants access to the array which `filter` is being called on but doesn't care about the index, they must supply a second argument nonetheless to use the third, array argument. Note that `_` is just like any other variable, and you can still do whatever you do to a variable with it. It's just been commonly used as a throwaway variable.

If you wanted an explanation of the code, it just iterates through the array and checks the current element's index. The callback returns true if `a` (the current element being processed)'s index in `aa` (the array `filter` is being called on) is the last index the element appears. If it is, that means the element occurs nowhere else in the array, and thus filters out duplicate elements.

---

By "commonly used" I mean that many languages adopt this practice. In languages such as Python, it's a well-known standard. Other languages such as SQL, Haskell, and Scala use this to (although Haskell as a pattern).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you already mean but it doesn't filter duplicate elements. Instead, if an element is duplicated, all occurrences of that element are filtered. See my answer for snippets illustrating this.

Comment: @JustinTaddei I thought my answer implied this, it's clear from the explanation. Nothing's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Like you said

> What I been seeing in the docs is that Array.prototype.filter takes a callback function with an element, an index and an array.

So the callback function, `a` is the current element being evaluated, `_` will represent the current index of `a` and `aa` is the array that is currently being filtered, in this case `temp`

EDIT as per comment from @Andrew Li:

The `_` is just a placeholder. It is not getting used in the callback so to keep things simple, the `_` is used so that the callback can have access to `aa`, which is getting used.

Comment: Before the question got edited, it was not clear they wanted clarity on `_`. Also, why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

The argument would be better written as `(element, index, array) => . . .`

And yes. `_` (or `index`) is never used. It's only a placeholder so we can get access to the `aa` (or `array`) argument.

**For anyone trying to understand why the function works:**

*If you're unfamiliar with `Array.prototype.filter` have a look at the MDN Docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter*

This code only keeps the elements that are never repeated (only `3`, and `6` are kept in the following snippet because there's only one of each). This happens because, for example, if `element = 5` then `array.indexOf(element) === 8` (which is basicly `array.firstIndexOf(element)`) so then `array.lastIndexOf(element) === 10` and because `8 !== 10` the element (in this case, `5`) is left out comletely.

```js
var temp = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7];
temp = temp.filter((element, index, array) => array.indexOf(element) === array.lastIndexOf(element));
console.log(temp);
```

However, if you did the following instead, is would filter out any duplicates, leaving only one occurrence of each element because at some point `index` will be the same as `lastIndex`, meaning the element will be kept.

```js
var temp = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7];
temp = temp.filter((element, index, array) => index === array.lastIndexOf(element));
console.log(temp);
```

Comment: Honestly, the focus of the answer is not what it's asking. The use isn't asking about what the code does but rather what _ is and why it's there.